# Truth trees and validity

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm having trouble understanding this question. Taken from Richard Jeffrey's book "Formal Logic" (4ed).

Who Am I? (Find a snappy conclusion that closes the [truth] tree).

a) $ \forall x  Lxb, \forall x (Lbx \rightarrow Ixa).$ ("Ixa," x is me.)

b) $ \forall x(Bbx \rightarrow Ixa), Bbc$. ("B," begat; "a," me; "b," my father; "c," that man's father).

I know that I have to make up my own conclusion that will close all paths of the tree, but I'm having trouble understanding what the latter part of each sub question means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what $L$ means, so I'll concentrate on (b). The second sentence of (b), $Bbc$, just states "$b$ begat $c$", or in other words "my father begat that man's father". The first sentence is a little harder: $\forall x(Bbx \rightarrow Ixa)$. Read it in stages. First, we can translate the "$\forall x$": "for every $x$, $Bbx \rightarrow Ixa$". Next, translate the $\rightarrow$: "for every $x$, if $Bbx$ then $Ixa$". Translate the predicates: "for every $x$, if $b$ begat $x$ then $x$ is $a$". And finally, translate the constants: "for every $x$, if my father begat $x$, then $x$ is me."

The next step is to rephrase it in a way that's more natural, ideally without variables. So we have "For any person, if my father begat that person, then that person is me." Better: "Any person my father begat is me". Still a little awkward, so we can make it better: "The only person my father begat is me". Or even better: *"I am my father's only child."*

So we know "I am my father's only child" and that "my father begat that man's father". What's the immediate consequence?

Comment: Would the consequence would be that I am "that man's father", i.e. $ Ica $ ?

Comment: Yep! If the constants mean the same thing in (a), then the consequence is going to be a bit weirder, I think.